# Groovy. Is it possible to save a method into a var?

Tags: groovy

Well, I want to save a method into a var to call it later. I want something like this:

```
class A {
     def sayHello() {
         "Hello"
     }
}

def a = new A()
def sayHelloMethod = a.sayHello
def result = sayHelloMethod()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found that the method pointer operator (.&) can be used to store a reference to a method in a variable.

```
class A {
   def sayHello() {
      "Hello"
   }
}

def a = new A()
def sayHelloMethod = a.&sayHello
assert a.sayHello() == sayHelloMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
class A {
     def sayHello() {
         "Hello"
     }
}

def a = new A()
def sayHelloClosure = { a.sayHello }
def result = sayHelloClosure.call()
```

Comment: Props. I like this approach and have now used it myself. Thanks.